# Create and run a batch file containing special chars as accent

Tags: c#, batch-file, character-encoding

I am actualy creating a batch file from my C# application. (path contains accents for example)

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("file.bat", false))
{
    var path = "C:\directory_été"; 
    var whoot = @"@echo off" + Environment.NewLine + @"pushd %~dp0" + Environment.NewLine + path; // where path contains accents and such
    file.Write(whoot);
}
```

When opening the .bat file with notepad.exe, everything looks written perfectly.
Then my app is running the batch.

```
var Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & start /b \"myBatchTitle\" \"C:\\file.bat\"";
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.Start(Info);
```

The batch returns an error because it is not finding the "path" because it changed the accents into some garbage characters.
So, everything looks ok in the .bat itself, but when running it, it fails reading correctly cause of the encoding.(path echoed as "directory_ÚtÚ" when batch is ran, i cant even copy the Ú from cmd prompt cause its printed correctly here then lol)

How can i fix this please? (and not MANUALLY change characters one by one)
Or isn't there a way to encode the string in C# to OEM something so it will be reading correctly? (example change é to Ú already, for ALL characters)

(For more infos, the created batch file is running 7zip command line version, and the path i submit to it is containing the accents and such)

*Otherway, do you know any portable-command-line alternative, accepting real UTF8 encoding so ll languages will be accepted?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the appropriate code page is for C:\directory_été (maybe you do, since you are dealing with this file).  You can try codepage 863, which is for Canadian French.

In any case, if you know the codepage, you could try changing code page via `chchp xxx` where `xxx` is the number identifying the code page you want to switch to. So you could try `chcp 863`. You can put this in your batch file before you use the path with the accents.

Comment: i am testing the batch file without the C# directly. and using `chcp 65001 > nul && command_here` doesn't fix anything :/

Comment: Too bad.  I hoped that would do it.